# How can I do Touch to pause on speech recognition on Google Speech Recognition?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I make a project based on speech reconginition. It works fine.
When I click button google speech recognition is starting and when the speech is ended it automatically ends. But I want the user touch to pause speech recognition whenever the user wants.
My screen is like this:

[image]

note: in swiftkey keyboard on play store , they do what i want.

Comment: You write the code for that

Comment: how ? I already wrote code but when I click red speak button after talk it cancel my recognition.